# Gcc - c++ - force trailing return to functions

Tags: c++, gcc

After reading [gcc warning page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

I would like to force every function to have their return type defined

```
auto f() -> force_this_return_type_presence{}
```

I would have liked a gcc warning turned into an error with `Werror` but I could not find anything around this idea.

Anything I missed?

Thanks

Comment: You probably can't using gcc, as its valid C++ without trailing return type. Clang tidy might be helpful.

Comment: @6c00h This doesn't apply to lambda since the return type of lambda is deduced by the compiler when omitted.

Comment: also when it can be deduced? why?

Comment: Hmm.. I will stick to clang tidy then and enforce devs to watch for this.. Thanks guys

Comment: Maybe compile in C++11 standard instead of C++14 or later? I would not recommend this however.

Comment: @prapin: thanks for the suggestion, that's an option, but we use c++20 here